# Javascript .match and .test inside foreach loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, converters

I've been staring at this problems for hours and I think I need another set of eyes.

I am trying to find measurements within a table and loop through them finding all the mm and convert them to in.

I believe I have everything OK, but in console it keeps throwing errors.

Can anyone help?

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8p6m9azd/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#convert').click(function(){

    //each data in table
    $('td').each(function(index, value){

        //find mm
        if(/[mm]+/g.test(value)){
            console.log('We found a mm');

            //find numbers inside
            numbers = value.match(/[-+]?\d*(\.(?=\d))?\d+/g);

            if(numbers){
                arrayLength = numbers.length;

                //find and replace
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    newnum = Math.ceil(numbers[i] / 0.039);
                }
                    value = value.replace(numbers[i],newnum);
                }
        } 
    });         
});
});
```

Comment: `[mm]` wont find `mm`. The brackets can be interpreted as `or`. `[abc]` matches a or b or c. So it should be `(mm)+` instead

Comment: /[mm]+/g could be replaced with /mm/g

Comment: @Fuzzyma that is why there is a + after .

Comment: So you are trying to find m OR m and that multiple times. Sounds wired ^^.

Answer (score 3):

`value` is a DOM node, you probably want to get the `textContent`.

```
$('td').each(function(index, value) {
  // value.textContent is what you want
```

easiest way to check that is:

```
$('td').each(function(index, value) {
  value = value.textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/8p6m9azd/8/
It converts all the cells with the class "conv mm" and makes sure that the cells aren't converted twice.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#convert').click(function () {

        //each data in table
        $('td.conv.mm').each(function (index, value) {
            value = $(value);
            //find mm
            if (/[mm]+/g.test(value.html())) {
                console.log('We found a mm');

                //find numbers inside
                numbers = value.html().match(/[-+]?\d*(\.(?=\d))?\d+/g);

                if (numbers) {
                    arrayLength = numbers.length;
                    //find and replace
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                        newnum = Math.ceil(Number.parseFloat(numbers[i]) / 0.039);
                        value.html(value.html().replace(numbers[i], newnum));

                    }

                    value.removeClass('mm')
                    value.html(value.html().replace('mm', 'in'));
                    value.addClass('in')
                }

            }


        });

    });
});
```